# How to divide two Pandas Pivoted Tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have two Pandas pivoted tables: one with total sales and other with sales count.

Examples: 
[image]
[image]

How to generate a third table with result of division between the previous two tables?

Example:
[image]

Ps: Emphasizing the two tables (Sales Amount and Sales count) are result from pivot_table function.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

Scott, I tried what you had suggested, but I didn't get how to fill the parameters of Multiindex part...

How to fill these parameters?

Here is my code:

```
df1 = getDFFaturAgencyFeeSemRDABR(filtros)

df1['Month'] = df1['DataFatura'].dt.strftime('%m')     
df1['Net Agency Fee'] = df1['Agency Fee']- df1['Total Rebate']              

dfSalesAmount = pd.pivot_table(df1,                             
                    values=['Net Agency Fee'],
                    columns=['Branch'],
                    index=['Month'], 
                    aggfunc=np.sum,
                    margins=True,
                    margins_name='Total',                        
                    fill_value=0).astype(np.float64).round(2)

dfCount = pd.pivot_table(df1,                             
                    values=['Vessels Count'],
                    columns=['Branch'],
                    index=['Month'], 
                    aggfunc=np.sum,
                    margins=True,
                    margins_name='Total',                        
                    fill_value=0).astype(np.float64).round(2)


indx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Net Agency Fee'], ???????])

indx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Vessels Count'],???????])

colind1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Month'], ??????])


dfSalesAmount.index = indx1

dfSalesAmount.columns = colind1
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you try `DataFrame.div`?

Comment: Hi Parfait! Yes, I tried this ( dfResult = dfSalesAmount.div(dfCount).T )... but I received the message "cannot convert float NaN to integer".

Comment: Can you add df1.to_dict() and df2.to_dict() results to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using dataframe slicing and `div`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1500,1700,2500,5700],
                   'B':[3000,2800,1804,7604],
                   'C':[2000,1500,1985,5485],
                   'D':[6500,6000,6289,18789]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,10,13,27],
                   'B':[10,11,15,36],
                   'C':[25,80,33,138],
                   'D':[39,101,61,201]})

indx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Total Sales'],['Vitoria','Rio De Janeiro','Sao Paulo','Total']])

indx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Sales Count'],['Vitoria','Rio De Janeiro','Sao Paulo','Total']])

colind1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Month'],[1,2,3,'Total']])

df1.index = indx1

df1.columns = colind1

df1

df2.index = indx2

df2.columns = colind1

df_out = df1.loc['Total Sales'].div(df2.loc['Sales Count'])

df_out = df_out.iloc[:-1,:-1].assign(idx1='Sales Average')\
               .set_index('idx1', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                                   Month                       
                                       1           2          3
idx1                                                           
Sales Average Vitoria         375.000000  300.000000  80.000000
              Rio De Janeiro  170.000000  254.545455  18.750000
              Sao Paulo       192.307692  120.266667  60.151515
```

Comment: Scott, I answered your message in my thread to clarify... thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Scott, how to atend the below parameters in a dynamic dataframe?
indx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Net Agency Fee'], ???????])
indx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Vessels Count'],???????])
colind1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Month'], ??????])

Comment: Sorry, Diego. I  am confused.  The first part of this answer is just setting up your input dataframes.   The line of code with the div method is the solution.  Pandas general does all operations with index alignment, hence if you have to dataframes with different indexing, pandas will align the index and perform the method.

Comment: Thanks Scott! Worked well! =)